# javascript storing information for a lot of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, click

Every time the user clicks on something on the site/screen, I need to save the information of the click, the id of the tag and a few other attributes that are related to that click. I need to save all the info.

What is the best way to do this type of thing, using javascript?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) is the best way to go?

Comment: and then i can save it all in a array in order to be able to get the info again? do you have a example for how that will work? with a array?

Comment: `$('body').data('myData',[1,2,3,4,5])` stores the array [1,2,3,4,5] to the body element (you probably want to use another selector), to fetch the data agan you can: `$('body').data('myData')` which will return the array [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: and you can also store objects. like `{x:10,y:20,id:'id'}`

Comment: thats great, but if i need to save info for every click that the user does, is this still helpful? wont that be complicated?

Comment: just create an empty array like so $('body').data('myData',[]) in an initialization phase. then for each click you fetch the array ´var myArray = $('body').data('myData'); myArray.push({x:1,y:20.id:'id1'})´ and then push it back on the body element `$('body').data('myData',myArray)`. Im unsure wheter you need this last step, it depends on if you get a reference to the array or not from the fetch call.

Comment: sorry to drive you crazy, but now after i push the new array to the global array, how do i fetch that info?

Comment: You mean fetch the last item on the array? `var myArray = [1,2,3,4]; myArray[myArray.length-1]` will fetch the last item on the array.

Comment: ok, now that i have all my info for all the click in the $(body).data(), how can i get only info for one of the clicks? or for all?

Comment: `$('body').data('myArray')[clickIndex]` will return the data of a single click defined by clickIndex. and `$('body').data('myArray')` will still fetch all click events.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to associate any object with an element:

```
$(selector).click(function(e) {
    $(this).data("information", {
        event: e,
        id: this.id
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. and then i just put that in to a array so i can go back to  it later? also how do i refer to that information again after i put in to a array? ill appreciate if you can give me full example. thanks